# Как в PyQt5 активировать/деактивировать Dial ручку при помощи radioButton?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты, qdial

Изначально в *Qt Designer* `dial` ручке я задал свойство `Enabled False`. В данной задаче ручка должна активироваться при активном `radioButton` и деактивироваться при активации `radioButton_2`.

1. Как это реализовать в коде?
2. Возможно ли подобные настройки делать непосредственно в *Qt Designer*? чтобы избавляться от лишнего написания кода?

***main.py***

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

CONFIG_FILE_NAME = 'config.ini'


class New(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(New, self).__init__()
        loadUi("RButton_Dial_save.ui", self)

        self.Exit.clicked.connect(self.close)

        self.dial.setMinimum(0)
        self.dial.setMaximum(10)
        self.dial.setValue(5)

        self.spinbox.setRange(5, 100)
        self.spinbox.setValue(5)

        self.load_settings()

        self.dial.setMinimum(self.spinbox.value() - 5)
        self.dial.setMaximum(self.spinbox.value() + 5)
        self.dial.setValue(self.spinbox.value())
        self.dial.valueChanged.connect(self.dial_changed)

        self.spinbox.valueChanged.connect(self.spinbox_changed)

        self.statusbar = self.statusBar()
        self.statusbar.showMessage('Hello World', msecs=2000)

        self.dial.setValue(self._dial)

        self.radioButton.clicked.connect(self.spinbox_changed)

    def save_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)
        settings.setValue('DialValue', self.dial.value())
        settings.setValue('SpinBoxValue', self.spinbox.value())

    def load_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)

        self.dial.setValue(
            int(settings.value('DialValue', self.spinbox.value())))
        self.spinbox.setValue(
            int(settings.value('SpinBoxValue', self.spinbox.value())))

        self._dial = int(settings.value('DialValue', self.spinbox.value()))

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.save_settings()

    def spinbox_changed(self, value):
        self.dial.setEnabled(True)
        self.dial.setMinimum(value - 5)
        self.dial.setMaximum(value + 5)
        self.dial.setValue(value)

    def dial_changed(self, value):
        self.statusbar.showMessage(f'dial.value = {value}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    window = New()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

***RButton_Dial_save.ui***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Fixed" vsizetype="Fixed">
    <horstretch>0</horstretch>
    <verstretch>0</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="maximumSize">
   <size>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>600</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true"/>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="minimumSize">
    <size>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>600</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <property name="maximumSize">
    <size>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>600</height>
    </size>
   </property>
   <widget class="QGroupBox" name="groupBox">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>10</x>
      <y>30</y>
      <width>761</width>
      <height>211</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="title">
     <string>GroupBox</string>
    </property>
    <widget class="QDial" name="dial">
     <property name="enabled">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>200</x>
       <y>130</y>
       <width>100</width>
       <height>55</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="wrapping">
      <bool>false</bool>
     </property>
     <property name="notchesVisible">
      <bool>true</bool>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QPushButton" name="Exit">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>650</x>
       <y>30</y>
       <width>93</width>
       <height>28</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>Выход</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QSpinBox" name="spinbox">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>300</x>
       <y>20</y>
       <width>111</width>
       <height>22</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>230</x>
       <y>90</y>
       <width>95</width>
       <height>20</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>RButton 1</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
    <widget class="QRadioButton" name="radioButton_2">
     <property name="geometry">
      <rect>
       <x>420</x>
       <y>90</y>
       <width>95</width>
       <height>20</height>
      </rect>
     </property>
     <property name="text">
      <string>RButton 2</string>
     </property>
    </widget>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: вместо clicked надо toggled https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#toggled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> void QAbstractButton::**toggled**(bool checked)
>
> Этот сигнал излучается всякий раз, когда проверяемая кнопка меняет свое состояние. **`checked`** имеет значение `true`, если кнопка отмечена, или `false`, если кнопка не отмечена.

я бы не стал связывать сигналы от разных объектов в один слот. Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSettings
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

CONFIG_FILE_NAME = 'config.ini'


class New(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(New, self).__init__()
        loadUi("RButton_Dial_save.ui", self)

        self.Exit.clicked.connect(self.close)

        self.dial.setMinimum(0)
        self.dial.setMaximum(10)
        self.dial.setValue(5)

        self.spinbox.setRange(5, 100)
        self.spinbox.setValue(5)

        self.load_settings()

        self.dial.setMinimum(self.spinbox.value() - 5)
        self.dial.setMaximum(self.spinbox.value() + 5)
        self.dial.setValue(self.spinbox.value())
        self.dial.valueChanged.connect(self.dial_changed)

        self.spinbox.valueChanged.connect(self.spinbox_changed)

        self.statusbar = self.statusBar()
        self.statusbar.showMessage('Hello World', msecs=2000)

        self.dial.setValue(self._dial)

#        self.radioButton.clicked.connect(self.spinbox_changed)
        self.radioButton.toggled.connect(self.rb_checked)                # +++
        self.spinbox.setEnabled(False)                                   # +++

    def save_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)
        settings.setValue('DialValue', self.dial.value())
        settings.setValue('SpinBoxValue', self.spinbox.value())

    def load_settings(self):
        settings = QSettings(CONFIG_FILE_NAME, QSettings.IniFormat)

        self.dial.setValue(
            int(settings.value('DialValue', self.spinbox.value())))
        self.spinbox.setValue(
            int(settings.value('SpinBoxValue', self.spinbox.value())))

        self._dial = int(settings.value('DialValue', self.spinbox.value()))

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.save_settings()

    def spinbox_changed(self, value):
#        self.dial.setEnabled(True)
        self.dial.setMinimum(value - 5)
        self.dial.setMaximum(value + 5)
        self.dial.setValue(value)

    def dial_changed(self, value):
        self.statusbar.showMessage(f'dial.value = {value}')

# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def rb_checked(self, checked):
        #print(f'{checked}') 
        if checked:
            self.dial.setEnabled(True)
            self.spinbox.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.dial.setEnabled(False)
            self.spinbox.setEnabled(False)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    window = New()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю за такие развернутые ответы. Именно такие информативные ответы ждут многие люди

Comment: @Владимир не надо пытаться все сделать в Qt Designer. Нарисовали форму и все, а логику пишите в основном классе.